# Как правильно реализовать совмещение?

Tags: java

Есть программа иерархии Библиотеки с абстрактным классом User и наследуемыми от него классами пользователей (LibrarianImpl, ReaderImpl, SupplierImpl, AdministratorImpl). Классы используют свои интерфейсы(Librarian, Reader, Supplier, Administrator).
Требуется создать новый класс SupplierAndReader, который бы давал возможность классу SupplierImpl использовать интерфейс Reader.

Интерфейс Reader:

```
public interface Reader { 

    public void takeBook(ReaderImpl reader, Book book); 
    public void returnBook(ReaderImpl reader, Book book); 
}
```

Класс SupplierAndReader:

````
```
public class SupplierAndReader implements Reader {

    public SupplierAndReader (SupplierImpl supplier) {

    }

    public void takeBook(SupplierImpl supplier, Book book) {
        System.out.println(supplier + " взял книгу " + book.title + " из библиотеки");
    }


    public void returnBook(SupplierImpl supplier, Book book) {
        System.out.println(supplier + " вернул книгу " + book.title + " в библиотеку");
    }

}
```
````

Текст ошибки:

```
java: com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.SupplierAndReader is not abstract and does not override abstract method returnBook(com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.ReaderImpl,com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.Book) in com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.Reader
```

Comment: Кроме компилятора на вас будет ругаться ваш преподаватель. Как минимум классы должны зависеть от ИНТЕРФЕЙСОВ, а не конкретных реализаций в виде `SupplierImpl`.  Без описания интерфейсов ничем не могу вам помочь. К тому же экстрасенсы молчат о тексте вашей ошибки.

Comment: @ArchDemon Интерфейс Reader:

public interface Reader {
    public void takeBook(ReaderImpl reader, Book book);
    public void returnBook(ReaderImpl reader, Book book);
}

Текст ошибки: 

java: com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.SupplierAndReader is not abstract and does not override abstract method returnBook(com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.ReaderImpl,com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.Book) in com.company.abstractions_interfaces.library.Reader

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос. не нужно код писать в комментариях. они для этого не предназначены

Comment: почему у вас в классе `SupplierAndReader` нет методов `public void takeBook(ReaderImpl reader, Book book)` и `public void returnBook(ReaderImpl reader, Book book)`???

Comment: @ArchDemon Я понимаю, что для, того чтобы это скомпилировалось нужно добавить оба метода интерфейса в том виде, в котором они указаны, но тогда вызывать методы 'takeBook()' и 'returnBook()' смогут вызывать только объекты класса 'ReaderImpl', но мне надо, чтобы они вызывались и объектами 'SupplierImpl'.

Comment: ну так  ` implements Supplier`. Ну и вообще у вас такая дичь написана. Непонятно что конкретно вам нужно.